# What advice would you give someone on redesigning forms for a digital workflow?

Tags: document-design

Imagine that your company has decided to move to a truly digital workflow. Not necessarily paper->online but that's the easiest example. Perhaps it's "let's move the real estate paperwork to the cloud" or "automate the approval process for a corporate project launch, with Legal and Regulatory oversight." Or something simpler.

A lot of processes duplicate ‘the way we’ve done it’ without rethinking the problem. If I put together a list of useful advice what should be included?

What did you learn the hard way? Or, what tips would you hope to read before you got started on such an endeavor?

Comment: Welcome to UX StackExchange. Since this is a question/answer site (one correct answer is marked per question), could you help us answer this by editing your question to give us some information on what you've been trying in your digital transformation effort, what's working, and what might be blocking you? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a forum for open ended discussions. Your question should focus on a specific problem and be answerable within a few paragraphs. Check out the [help] for more information.